# Can't access Apache installed on virtual machine (KVM) running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, kvm-virtualization

VPS: KVM (SolusVM),
VM OS: Ubuntu 18.04,
Network card: Virtio / Intel Pro 1000,

I can ping VM IP 21X.XXX.XXX.XXX from my machine(at home). But cannot access Apache port 80 using 21X.XXX.XXX.XXX or domain.

I installed docker in my VM, which is also not accessible outside using  21X.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000.

Am I forgetting something to configure?

Note:
If I curl 21X.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000 **inside VNC**, it works but not on internet.

Comment: And what exactly is the meaning of "cannot access Apache"? Timeout, connection refused, access denied,...?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is Apache service up and running? - ***ps auxxw*** can help you here
2. Is it bound to port 80? - ***nmap*** or ***netstat*** can help you here
3. Is it accessible locally? - ***wget*** or ***curl*** can help you here
4. Is your firewall allowing incoming connections to the respective ports?
5. Is your VPS placing your VM behind a vnet?

Perform the same checks for every service that you can't access.